# Bash-Script: rename files in folder order by file-date

Tags: linux, rename, date

I want to rename files in order of file-date; from example:

```
file_1.pdf
file_2.pdf
```

to:

```
file_1_ONE.pdf
file_2._TWO.pdf
```

The script must rename the first file to "ONE" ordered by file-date.

Comment: You need to rename the files to use word-based numbering? Or is that `ONE` a place-holder? (If so, please [edit] your question to show what you really want.) Why does the second file get `._TWO` added (with a `.`), but the first file gets only `_ONE`?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `zsh` shell and the `number` utility found in `/usr/games` on some BSD systems (on e.g. Ubuntu systems, this would be available from the `bsdgames` package):

```
number=1
for file in ./file_*.pdf(.Om); do
    mv "$file" "${file%.pdf}_$(number -l "$number" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]').pdf"
    number=$(( number + 1 ))
done
```

The `(.Om)` is a modifier to the preceding pattern that is specific to the `zsh` shell.  It makes the pattern expand to a list of filenames of regular files that is ordered by the mtime timestamp (last modified time) with the oldest file first.

The command `number -l "$number" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` would call `number` with the current value of `$number` and would return the English word corresponding to this in upper case, e.g. `ONE`, `TWO`, `THREE` etc.  This would be prepended with the filename without its filename suffix and with an underscore, and the string `.pdf` would be added to the end.

Alternatively, to avoid `tr`:

```
number=1
for file in ./file_*.pdf(.Om); do
    en_number=$(number -l "$number")
    mv "$file" "${file%.pdf}_${en_number:u}.pdf"
    number=$(( number + 1 ))
done
```

`${en_number:u}` would convert `$en_number` (the output from `number`) to upper case.  The `:u` modifier is `zsh`-specific and `${variable:u}` corresponds to `${variable^^}` in `bash`.

Testing:

```
$ for name in file_{1..10}.pdf; do touch "$name"; sleep 2; done
$ ls -lt
total 4
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_10.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_9.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_8.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_7.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_6.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_5.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_4.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_3.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_2.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_1.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  163 Jan 31 13:26 script.sh
```

```
$ zsh script.sh
$ ls -lt
total 4
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_10_TEN.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_9_NINE.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_8_EIGHT.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_7_SEVEN.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_6_SIX.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_5_FIVE.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_4_FOUR.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_3_THREE.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_2_TWO.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Jan 31 13:28 file_1_ONE.pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  163 Jan 31 13:26 script.sh
```

Answer (score -2):

This script lists the name of each file in the current folder in order of creation time along with an increasing counter. Change the `echo` line to do what you need :)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

((counter=1))

for f in $(ls -1ct); do
    echo $f-$counter
    ((counter+=1))
done
```

Comment: Using `$(ls -1ct)` is a bad habit. What if OP wants `ONE` instead of `1`.

Comment: See [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\` (and what do to instead)?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985)

Comment: This would rename `somefile.pdf` to `somefile.pdf-44` (for an example value of `44`).